# Navigation menu not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I fix these 3 issues facing my bootstrap navigation bar:

- Menu cannot collapse properly when resized (window made smaller)
- Have the icons beside the menu links instead of below them
- Have the sign up/login button link to another page when the window is resized

Here is a demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/whywymam/zpdpsuLn/

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">

      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

          <navbar>

              <div class="upperRow">

               <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="#" class="brand navbar-brand"> <img src="image/logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
               </div>

               <div id="btnTopInline">

                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right imgicon hidden-xs">

                       <li>
                         <div class="indivColl">
                            <a href="signupLogin.php">
                               <img src="image/jobseekerlogo.png" class="indi">
                               <p class="indit">Job Seeker</p>
                            </a>
                         </div>
                       </li>

                       <li>
                         <div id="empColl">
                            <a href="signupLoginEmp.php">
                               <img src="image/employerlogo.png" class="emp">
                               <p class="empt">Employer</p>
                            </a>
                         </div>
                       </li>

                   </ul>

               </div>

               <!--                for tablet and mobile view-->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-login pull-right visible-xs">
                    <a href="signupLoginEmp.php">
                        Employer<br>Log In
                    </a>
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-login pull-right visible-xs">
                    <a href="signupLogin.php">
                        Job Seeker<br>Log In
                    </a>
                </button>

              </div>

            <div class="middleRow">

                <div class="navbar-inner navbar-default navbar-static-top navcolor">

                          <div class="navbar-header ">

                              <!--button to appear when display is on mobile device-->
                              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                              </button>

                          </div>

                          <div class="nav-collapse collapse-in" id="nav-collapse">

                              <ul class="nav  navbar-nav center-block">
                                <li><a href="home.php">Home<img src="image/home.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.php">About<img src="image/about.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="pyw.php">Prove Job<img src="image/PYW.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Job<img src="image/jobs.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="rescources.php">Resources<img src="image/resource.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                             </ul>

                          </div>


                    </div> <!-- end inner navbar -->

            </div> <!-- end middle row -->

          </navbar>

      </div> <!-- end col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 -->

  </div><!-- end container -->
```

CSS:

```
.img-responsive {
max-width: 60%;
margin-bottom: 15%;
padding-top: -3%;
}
.imgicon {
padding-left: 50%;
margin-top: -2%;
}

.middleRow{
padding-top: 10%;
margin-top: 5%;
}

.navcolor{
background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default {
margin-top: 3%;
}

.navbar-nav {
float:none;
margin: 0 auto;
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
text-align: center;
}

#btnTopInline{
display: inline-block;
float: right;
clear: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  .nav-collapse{
        display: inline;
  }
  }
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: in your demo, everything seems fixed....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code i have made some modification in html and css

for the toggal button to work use `data-target=".nav-collapse"` insted of `data-target=".navbar-collapse"`

for icons beside the menu links add img tag inside ancor tag.

below are changes

```
<body>
         <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
               <div class="container">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                     <a href="#" class="brand navbar-brand"> <img src="image/logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right imgicon hidden-xs">
                     <div id="indivColl">
                        <a href="signupLogin.php">
                           <img src="image/jobseekerlogo.png" class="indi">
                           <p class="indit">Job Seeker</p>
                        </a>
                     </div>
                     <div id="empColl">
                        <a href="signupLoginEmp.php">
                           <img src="image/employerlogo.png" class="emp">
                           <p class="empt">Employer</p>
                        </a>
                     </div>
                  </ul>
                  <!--                for tablet and mobile view-->
                  <button type="submit" id="btn-login-header" class="btn btn-login pull-right visible-xs mobile-login" 
                     id="header-mobile-login-button" data-target="#indivColl">
                  Employer<br>Log In
                  </button>
                  <button type="submit" id="btn-login-header" class="btn btn-login pull-right visible-xs mobile-login" 
                     id="header-mobile-login-button" data-target="#empColl">
                  Job Seeker<br>Log In
                  </button>

                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                  <span class="icon-bar">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>

                  <div class="nav-collapse collapse in" id="navbar-collapse">
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="home.php">Home<img src="image/home.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.php">About<img src="image/about.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="pyw.php">Prove Your Worth<img src="image/PYW.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Job<img src="image/jobs.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="rescources.php">Resources<img src="image/resource.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
   </body>
```

add this in css

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
      .nav-collapse{
            display: block;
      }
 }
```

Comment: How do I ensure that the navigation menu is at the center of the page at all screen sizes? I've tried using center-block and nav-justified but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First: For the responsive layout work the bootstrap need to work with rows and  columns. You need to put the navbar inside.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <navbar>
         </navbar>
    </div>
</div>
```

Second: I don't test, but i think which inside the li of navbar you need to create a div with class containing text-align: center; or put this class in the li. Inside the div put the text and icon, each one with a class, containing float: left and clear: both.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right imgicon hidden-xs">
            <div id="indivColl">
            <a href="signupLogin.php"><img src="image/jobseekerlogo.png" class="indi"><p class="indit">Job Seeker</p></a>
            </div>

            <div id="empColl">
            <a href="signupLoginEmp.php"><img src="image/employerlogo.png" class="emp"><p class="empt">Employer</p></a>
            </div>
        </ul>
```

Above you need to put each div inside a li. Insert the class in the img and trade the p tag to a span tag, after, add the same class to the span. 
The example is a supposition, i don't test but you can search more about the float and clear in www.w3cschools.com

The logic of navbar in your code is totaly wrong. You have a navbar inside a navbar with two containers. You need to review the concepts of bootstrap, html and css dude! Compare this with yours:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navcolor">
```

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> <img src="image/logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
</div>

<!-- for tablet and mobile view-->
<button type="submit" id="btn-login-header" class="btn btn-login pull-right navbar-btn visible-xs mobile-login" id="header-mobile-login-button" data-target="#indivColl">  Job Seeker Log In </button>
<button type="submit" id="btn-login-header" class="btn btn-login pull-right navbar-btn visible-xs mobile-login" id="header-mobile-login-button" data-target="#empColl"> Employer Log In </button>

<div class="navbar-header">
  <!--button to appear when display is on mobile device-->
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="home.php">Home</a><img src="image/home.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About</a><img src="image/about.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></li>
    <li><a href="pyw.php">Prove Your Worth</a><img src="image/PYW.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></li>
    <li><a href="#">Job</a><img src="image/jobs.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></li>
    <li><a href="rescources.php">Resources</a><img src="image/resource.png" width="75" height="65" alt="" title="" /></li>
    <li class="imgicon hidden-xs">
      <div id="indivColl">
        <a href="signupLogin.php"><img src="image/jobseekerlogo.png" class="indi"><p class="indit">Job Seeker</p></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="imgicon hidden-xs">
      <div id="empColl">
        <a href="signupLoginEmp.php"><img src="image/employerlogo.png" class="emp"><p class="empt">Employer</p></a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I doesnt enter in details with css or the completely bootstrap rules but i think this code can useful for you. And doesnt forgot the classes with float and clear ^^

This will be a way to do. Bye, like my answer if served !